# sql query to get the list of floors

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has

```
customer_id     floors
1234               12
1234                7
1234               -
1234               12
3456               1
3456               1
3476               2
3476               9

...
...
```

I want to get a report that will show something like this (count of floors by customer. Please notice that if the entry is duplicated by the customer for floor then it should be counted only once)

```
customers          no_of_floors
1234                   3
3456                   1
3476                   2
....
....
```

so far I have this

```
SELECT count(customer_id) AS total, customer_id FROM floors GROUP BY customer_id, floors;
```

but that does not seem to work.

Any idea

Comment: What is hospital_id? What is floor_name? The query doesn't match the table presented.

Comment: Your query uses columns that are not in your sample data, things like `hospital_id` and `customers`.  Can you fix the question?

Comment: No you haven't. Where does floor name come from? And what is your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: you are right. floors

Comment: why does primary key matter here?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm just nosey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you just want a count of distinct floors by customer:

```
select   customer_id,
         count(distinct floors)
from     floors
group by customer_id
having   count(distinct floors) between 6 and 9
```

Comment: is there a way I can do HAVING count(distinct floors) > 5 and less than 10?

Comment: I guess I am not about the right HAVING statement to use for between 2 values

Answer (score 2):

Close!

```
SELECT count(distinct floors) AS total, customer_id FROM floors GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Comment: late though, very late